# Same actions on same id, how to simplify?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do something like this, I feel this can be simplified, how can I do it?

```
$('#specificId').find('.class1').addClass('classA');
$('#specificId').find('.class2').addClass('classB');
$('#specificId').find('.class3').addClass('classC');
```

Can this be shortened to

```
$('#specificId').find('.class1, .class2, .class3').addClass('classA, classB, classC');
```

Comment: `$('#specificId').find('.class1, .class2, .class3').addClass('classA, classB, classC');` will add all classes not specific.

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie Good point, tried and all latter classes have been added to each former class, so not what I wanted.

Comment: Only thing you can do to improve that code would be to set `$('#specificId')` into a variable. `var elem = $('#specificId'); elem.find()....` Other than that there is no short cuts other than writing other code that makes it a bit more complicated.

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie not a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that in a single operation. However you could do it in a loop over the properties of an object:

```js
var obj = {
  class1: 'classA',
  class2: 'classB',
  class3: 'classC'
}

var $el = $('#specificId');
$.each(obj, function(key, value) {
  $el.find(`.${key}`).addClass(value);
});
```

It's not necessarily more simple, but it's certainly more extensible.

Comment: I would also prefer @Mamun's solution as it works for a changed HTML as well.

Comment: That's true, although if the HTML changes you still need to update the `.classN, ...` selector string so a JS change is necessary in either case.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Why use ```$el = $('#specificId')``` rather than ```el = $('#specificId')```? the extra ```$``` seems unnecessary?

Comment: @thinkvantagedu It's a common convention to prefix variable names containing jqueryobjects with a `$` sign. This makes it easier to spot if jQuery methods can be used on the contained object.

Comment: @connexo I read about it, is it really necessary? Not very convinced

Comment: It's not necessary, but as @connexo mentioned, it's a naming convention to make it clear that the value of this variable is a jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

I will go for [data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attribute:

```js
$('#container').find('.class1, .class2, .class3').each(function(){
  $(this).addClass($(this).data('class'));
});
```

```css
.classA{
  color: red;
}
.classB{
  color: green;
}
.classC{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="class1" data-class="classA">class1</div> 
  <div class="class2" data-class="classB">class2</div> 
  <div class="class3" data-class="classC">class3</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution although a little redundant; if you can add the `data` attribute to the HTML, why not just add the `class` in the first place?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Because it might be wanted to happen only in case of an event.

Comment: That's very true